# Will isopropyl alcohol dissolve the coating/paint of a notebook?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solubility, metal, alcohols

The notebook is a Dell Inspiron 6400 and the coating/paint is the silver on the palmrest and back cover.

It says 99,4% on the container of the isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: No way to know without trying it. If you're willing to risk it, put a little of the alcohol on a q-tip and rub it on a less visible spot of the laptop to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't really know until you try it because there doesn't appear to be any info about what they used as a coating. Having said that, isopropanol isn't a superbly strong organic solvent so while it may remove some of the coating, it's not likely to immediately eat through your laptop like how acetone might. Still, follow user137's advice and test it on a very small area before you try anything else, and give it time before you go using it everywhere else. If you don't see any damage and you decide to go through with whatever it is you want to do (I assume cleaning it), just make sure you wipe it off with a damp cloth (water) followed by a dry cloth as soon as you get the results you want to minimize any possible damage.

Comment: Thank you. I have contacted Dell and they advise against using alcohol.